# Oracle apex database connected but invalid username and password in java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-apex

I have database in oracle apex name **ALHAMD**. When i connect through oracle apex browser based databse it connected fine but when i create database connection through java code and try to connect from their. **An error of invalid username and password has occur**. But when i run my code multiple times my database user has been locked and then i have to unlock my user through admin user in oracle apex. I have check my username and password multiple times its same no changes also try multiple version of ojdbc library like 6,7,& 8 but no effect.

Comment: If you're logging in through the APEX builder (where you're entering a workspace, username, and password), you're logging in to an APEX account not an Oracle database account.

Comment: Thanks, the Issue has been resolved.